# Retain setTimeout() After Page Refreshes or Moves To Another Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I need to show my alert message after 15 minutes, but it doesn't work if the page refreshes or if I change pages. I am doing this on the same web page. When I press a button, it should call the `showPopUp()` method. I am using asp.net with version Visual Studios 2005.

```
function showPopUp(){
  setTimeout(function() {alert("Warning");}, 5000);
}
 
function delayer(){
  showPopUp();
}
```

Comment: @Travis J I don't get why you guys declared this comment offtopic. I put enough code in and comments to explain the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store the initial time in local storage
2. Whenever the page loads, compare the value in local storage to the current time and start the timeout again from where you left off.

So something like this (untested):

```
var waitTime = 900000; // 15 minutes
var executionTime;
var initialTime = localStorage.getItem("initialTime");
if (initialTime === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("initialTime", (new Date()).getTime());
    executionTime = waitTime;
}
else {
    executionTime = parseInt(initialTime, 10) + waitTime - (new Date()).getTime();
    if (executionTime < 0) executionTime = 0;
}

setTimeout(function() { 
    alert("Warning"); 
    // reset the timeout to start from waitTime on page reload
    localStorage.removeItem("initialTime");
}, executionTime);
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use localStorage, you could store it in an asp.net session variable like so:

```
Session["InitialTime"] = (DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
```

Then do similar logic to the javascript code above and output the result as the second argument in the setTimeout function (but remember to convert seconds to milliseconds for the setTimeout).

Comment: +1. Note that it is not possible to automatically save and restore callbacks used by the `setTimeout` call as they rely on state of JavaScript engine which is completely lost on refresh. One would have to explicitly design functions to be "restorable" after page refresh - so avoiding page refresh (i.e. using AJAX calls to refresh the page) may be better approach.

Comment: LocalStorage (or web storage) is fairly well supported, but just FYI it will not work on certain older browsers. If you follow this approach, I'd recommend taking a look at this http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage to make sure it's ok for your needs. That is a client-side only solution. Check this post out for the general idea of a client/server solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883676/retaining-settimeout-call-even-after-page-reload.  It's written in PHP but hopefully it can help.

Comment: @PavelPatino yeah using server side code was my second thought. It's nice that it's possible for most browsers using just javascript though.

Comment: @dhtso Do I also need to store the time when I press the button?

Comment: It would probably be better to use `sessionStorage` here instead of `localStorage` (empties after browser closes).

Comment: What's the difference between sessionStorage and localStorage?

Comment: SessionStorage can be accessed in ASP.NET code directly, while LocalStorage must be manipulated with JavaScript. Also, not all browsers support LocalStorage. I believe IE 7 was the last version not to support it.

Comment: @kaser localStorage expires when the browser wants to remove it. With sessionStorage the information is deleted when you close the browser.

Comment: @Graham I don't believe the information in sessionStorage is ever sent to the server.

Comment: Oh crap, I was translating "SessionStorage" as the standard Session class in .NET.

Comment: @dhsto On the else statement, won't the execution time increase instead of lower every time the page reloads?

Comment: @kaser yes you're right. I wasn't thinking properly. Should be ok now (still untested though).

Comment: is there any way to store in php @DavidSherret ?